# How can I map and unmap objects under SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

*Is it possible to map and unmap mapper relationships for a specific class under SQLA without having to call `clear_mappers()`?*  The latter would be very silly and I suspect would perform really poorly.

---

**Backround**:

I have the following set up: A Slave class, creates some objects of type Fubar and send them via a socket to its Master.  The Master has a database ORM (via SQLAchemy) and knows how to map those objects to the database's table(s).  I do want the Slaves to not be aware of any database whatsoever.  All the database code is in the Master -- initialisation, creation of the engine, and `sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(...)` calls.   I was expecting it to be possible to abstract the whole database via the Master class.

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
Class 'Fubar' is mapped, but this instance lacks instrumentation.  This occurs when the instance is created before sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Fubar) was called.
```

This instance was created by the Slave which knows nothing of the database.  I do not wish it to know anything about the database or how to map Fubar to tables or anything at all.  I just want the Master to know how to do that.  Since the Master knows how to map those Fubar classes, I assumed it would be possible.  After all, the Master gets this class instance **after** it has mapped it to the database. Yet I am getting the above exception.

Anyone care to explains what am I doing that is wrong?

**Even more details...**

I am using the classic mapping and not in-class descriptive data as I do not wish anyone importing the class to know that it maybe stored in a database -- or rather they should not need to know the details of it.

Even using a `copy.deepcopy(fubar)` as a replacement, I am still getting that error. On the other hand, if I create a new Fubar object in the Master with the same data as the old (from network) Fubar, then I can use that.  I am even more confused now...

The reverse operation (sending a Fubar from the Master to a Slave) exhibit the same problem as the following is raised:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Cannot deserialize object of type <class 'Fubar'> - no mapper() has been configured for this class within the current Python process!
```

So, now the question is:

**How can I map and unmap objects under SQLAlchemy?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but are you probably looking for `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add()` and `.expunge()`?

Comment: @Simon: I do not think so.  The expunge calls remove objects from the session.  They do nothing to the underlying mapping of the object to database table(s).  I was calling `expunge_all()` in any case and this makes no difference to the `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError` error.

Comment: Here's my theory: sqlalchemy instruments instances when it loads then from the database, but also does some black magic, presumably to the `__new__` method, to instrument instances created using the constructor. You say you're tunneling your instances through a socket, which means they're being serialized/deserialized, which means the instrumentation might break or be removed completely, depending on how the serialization conflicts with sqlalchemy's mechanics.

Comment: @Simon: That is indeed what I think is happening as well but I would like a definitive answer.  Thank you for you comments though, they are helpful.